# Load a Header in wordpress

Tags: php, functions

I'm trying to added upload header in Wordpress but not upload the image but it print out the link of the header. How do I fix the problem the him have with wordpress.

```
<?php if ( get_header_image() != '' ) { 
    $banner = 'style="background-image:url('. header_image() .');"';
} else { 
    $banner = '';
} ?>

<main class="site-header" <?php echo $banner; ?> role='banner'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close - `get_header_image()` *returns* the URL of the image, whereas `header_image()` *echo's* out the URL.

Because you're setting your style tag in a variable and then echo'ing that, you need to use the function that *returns* the header image URL - so, like this:

```
$banner = 'style="background-image:url('. get_header_image() .');"';
```

Using `header_image()` will, as you found, echo out the URL directly, before you're actually wanting to do so in your case.

Incidentally, a lot of WordPress functions follow this same naming scheme. Generally, a function starting with `get_` will return the value, whereas a function starting with `the_`, or sometimes omitting it as in this case, will echo the value out.

Comment: Thank you very much teach me about this function. I think you should check out Codementor.io start mentor other developer and make money help people.